# jquery: how do I save and restore events?

Tags: jquery, events, restore

So I have this DOM chunk containing elements with different event handlers; I need to manipulate that DOM chunk with `$(parent).html(changed_dom_html)`.

changed_dom_html will contain some of the original elements, and so by using html() on their parent, their event handlers will fly out the window. How do I save their event handlers before using `parent.html()`, and restore them afterwards?

The old `data('events')` doesn't work anymore in the latest jQuery versions.

Comment: How do you create `changed_dom_html`? Is it a string?

Comment: You should be operating on DOM elements at a finer grain, modifying specific attributes as needed, rather than replacing the HTML in a block.

Comment: You can remove previous bindings and attach new ones after creating them `$('elm').off('events').on('events, 'elm', function()`

Comment: Yes Blender, string; You're right Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refactor your code a bit, but clone(true) will copy the elements and their event bindings.